# Can I deploy Retina with any JAVA version at all?

Tags: java

I tried Java 7, then Java 6 (Apple's) but my Java (Swing) desktop applications
behave as if I had a MacBook Pro instead of a MacBook Pro Retina.

Is there any setting I need to change somewhere?

Must I wait till ORACLE implements it in Java 7?

Comment: Can you add more detail?  What do you mean when you say that Java apps behave as if it's a MBP instead of a rMBP?

Answer (score 3):

Taken [from](http://lists.apple.com/archives/webobjects-dev/2012/Jul/msg00004.html) the instructions for how to modify Eclipse’s plist to get retina display. I can verify, this works. Perhaps something similar can be done with your app, assuming that the Mac version has a plist.

> 1. Do "Show package contents" on the Eclipse.app.
>
>    Edit Contents/Info.plist.
>
>    Just above
>
>    </dict>
>    </plist>
>
>    Place this:
>
>    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
>    <true/>

Following were instructions on how to clear the cached version, but in a development environment while you are creating your apps, they are probably not useful.

Comment: Good find! Links may break though, that's why fully documented answers are preferred on AD. Can you please summarize the solution in your answer?

Comment: @patrix: edited in response to comment!

Answer (score 1):

The time for waiting is over.  Oracle did implement this at last in
[jdk-7u40](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u40-relnotes-2004172.html)